# Where does linphone store the phonebook data?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I installed Linphone via appimage on a new computer.

The configuration seems to be stored `~/.config/linphone/linphonerc` - but where are saved phonenumbers stored so I can copy those over to the new computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~/.local/share/linphone/friends.db
```

It is an SQLite darabase file in vCard format.